# Extending Seq.sortBy in Scala

Tags: sorting, scala, collation

Say I have a list of names.

```
case class Name(val first: String, val last: String)

val names = Name("c", "B") :: Name("b", "a") :: Name("a", "B") :: Nil
```

If I now want to sort that list by last name (and if that is not enough, by first name), it is easily done.

```
names.sortBy(n => (n.last, n.first))
// List[Name] = List(Name(a,B), Name(c,B), Name(b,a))
```

But what, if I‘d like to sort this list based on some other collation for strings?

Unfortunately, the following does not work:

```
val o  = new Ordering[String]{ def compare(x: String, y: String) = collator.compare(x, y) }
names.sortBy(n => (n.last, n.first))(o)
// error: type mismatch;
// found   : java.lang.Object with Ordering[String]
// required: Ordering[(String, String)]
//   names.sortBy(n => (n.last, n.first))(o)
```

is there any way that allow me to change the ordering without having to write an explicit `sortWith` method with multiple `if`–`else` branches in order to deal with all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to extend the otherwise implicitly used Tuple2 ordering. Unfortunately, this means writing out `Tuple2` in the code.

```
names.sortBy(n => (n.second, n.first))(Ordering.Tuple2(o, o))
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, this almost does the trick:

```
names.sorted(o.on((n: Name) => n.last + n.first))
```

On the other hand, you can do this as well:

```
implicit val o  = new Ordering[String]{ def compare(x: String, y: String) = collator.compare(x, y) }
names.sortBy(n => (n.last, n.first))
```

This locally defined implicit will take precedence over the one defined on the `Ordering` object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what methods you think `collator` should have.

But you have the most flexibility if you define the ordering on the case class:

```
val o = new Ordering[Name]{
  def compare(a: Name, b: Name) =
    3*math.signum(collator.compare(a.last,b.last)) +
    math.signum(collator.compare(a.first,b.first))
}
names.sorted(o)
```

but you can also provide an implicit conversion from a string ordering to a name ordering:

```
def ostring2oname(os: Ordering[String]) = new Ordering[Name] {
  def compare(a: Name, b: Name) = 
    3*math.signum(os.compare(a.last,b.last)) + math.signum(os.compare(a.first,b.first))
}
```

and then you can use any String ordering to sort Names:

```
def oo = new Ordering[String] {
  def compare(x: String, y: String) = x.length compare y.length
}
val morenames = List("rat","fish","octopus")

scala> morenames.sorted(oo)
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(rat, fish, octopus)
```

---

Edit: A handy trick, in case it wasn't apparent, is that if you want to order by N things and you're already using compare, you can just multiply each thing by 3^k (with the first-to-order being multiplied by the largest power of 3) and add.

---

If your comparisons are very time-consuming, you can easily add a cascading compare:

```
class CascadeCompare(i: Int) {
  def tiebreak(j: => Int) = if (i!=0) i else j
}
implicit def break_ties(i: Int) = new CascadeCompare(i)
```

and then

```
def ostring2oname(os: Ordering[String]) = new Ordering[Name] {
  def compare(a: Name, b: Name) =
    os.compare(a.last,b.last) tiebreak os.compare(a.first,b.first)
}
```

(just be careful to nest them `x tiebreak ( y tiebreak ( z tiebreak w ) ) )` so you don't do the implicit conversion a bunch of times in a row).

(If you really need fast compares, then you should write it all out by hand, or pack the orderings in an array and use a while loop.  I'll assume you're not that desperate for performance.)

Comment: Hmm, I don’t know. Multiplying with 3^k looks smart but if something does not follow the -1/0/+1 convention, it won’t work of course. Also, it evaluates all comparisons at once whereas Tuple comparison stops when a difference is found.

Comment: @Debilski - Whoops, forgot the `math.signum` wrapper!  And yes, it does do a full eval--not ideal for speed, I agree.

Comment: I assumed `collator` was an instance of `java.text.Collator`.